# What happened to Heimdall's sword?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Heimdall's sword [Hofund](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hofund) is reported as "made by the Dwarf smiths of Nidavellir". It seems like it is also the "Thanos-killing kind". I was wondering why Thor didn't use it against Thanos (instead of the long process of forging a new weapon), but the link says:

> After having escaped Asgard's destruction, Hofund was physically broken during the subsequent massacre by Thanos.

I don't recall seeing this, so maybe someone can help pinpoint what this is referring to.

**What happened to Heimdall's sword?**

Comment: How does it seem like it's the Thanos-killing kind of weapon?

Comment: I suppose I'm just assuming this is true (or at least plausible) of all weapons forged on Nidavellir.

Comment: Thor is only proficient in hammers and axes, not in swords, and he didn't want to take the non-proficiency penalty on his to-hit rolls.

Comment: Not to mention, that according to a recent XKCD, a sword isn't even on the spectrum of possible Thor weapons: https://xkcd.com/2097/

Comment: thor used sword in Ragnarok

Comment: Dwarf craft have a purpuse. The "mighty sword of buttered toast" or the "Sword of carebear rainbow portal" will not be as effective as a weapon design for killing. It's the real life equivalent of magically blunt sword. Supers can use it and will cut through anything. But it's only because of the super strong user not the blade quality.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Hofund was indeed broken in the battle, we see this when Heimdall sends Hulk back to Earth by summoning the Bifrost.

[image: Heimdall sends Hulk back to Earth]

That is the last we see of the sword and then the ship is blown up using the Power Stone by Thanos. Therefore, it is quite likely that the sword was broken up further but we don't see it again to know for sure.

Comment: I'm consistently impressed with the amount of detail that was thought of and covered in these later films in the series.  It's like they thought of everything.   They have so many minor additions for evidence that answer these kinds of questions.